# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop Sharing (VNC) encryptiom / auth problem

Tags: encryption, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, remote

I know this has been discussed, but I can not find a permanent fix.

I enabled desktop sharing, unchecked "manually approve every access", set a password, and I'm trying from the local network, or via SSH port forwarding as I don't like to permanently open ports from the router.

All the VNC clients I tried say either "Unsupported auth method." "Unknown encryption type". I can see the connection is arriving to my computer with tcpdump, but the clients don't know Ubuntu's method.

A usable workaround is typing in "gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false" any time I'm going to remotely access. This means no encryption, but I'm running through a SSH tunnel, so I already have encryption.

I also tried the dconf thing, but I don't understand how to do it. (on the net I found that I need to disable remote access with dconf and set a password there, and whatever).
Does anyone know a fix, or maybe a VNC client that knows how to deal with Ubuntu's built in remote desktop server?

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary to reapply the gsettings fix each time - unless you are running a non-persistent live session...?

Comment: Nope, it's a full install. But that option seems to reset after reboot. Strange condition? Someone suggested to set it using dconf to make it persistent.

Comment: Well the dconf version would be `dconf write /desktop/gnome/remote-access/require-encryption false` I think - but I don't understand why the gsettings version should not persist.

Answer (score -2):

My response is probably very late for you, nevertheless it may help you if you haven't found another solution already.  The 100% vino compatible VNC client you can use is vinagre.  I am using it for years.  You can find it in the repos.  :)

p.s.  Vino is the name of the default VNC server in Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the encryption problem?

Comment: @guntbert: it *might* do.  The newer VNC client/servers have more stringent authentication and encryption then the original, so this just *might* be the answer the OP is looking for...